# Solution for continuous integration with remote cmd commands?

Tags: windows, tomcat, jenkins, cmd, continuous-integration

Though not clear from the title I'm looking for a solution, similar to what Jenkins does but with slightly different capabilities. I have 3 servers where I need to run some cmd commands and I need to be able to interpret their output.

I need this because I need to start 2 Apache Tomcat servers and the last one must start only if the first one has started correctly, so it has to wait for it to finish the start process. Also I need to make an svn update from the command line and check if that has completed correctly, copy/move some file on the disk, so basically all cmd commands.

I've tried to use Jenkins master/slave configuration with the log parser plugin to interpret the output and I can start tomcat, however I don't get an output in the console and I'm unable to make the second one wait for the first (by creating separate jobs for each one). I've read that this may be possible by creating some batch scripts or perhaps using ant tasks, but I was wondering if there is a better/standard way to accomplish these sort of tasks ?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

Comment: Ok, sorry about that, new to the community. Should I rephrase my question from a "recommended tool" to a "solution" perhaps ?

Comment: if you can do so, absolutely

Comment: Changed, hope it's better now. Thanks for the warning, will take into account in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could use multiple chained jobs to achieve your goal. Say you create a Jenkins job A to start the Apache on the first server, B job to start the Apache on the 2nd server. Configure job A so that when A succeeds, trigger job B. And then another job triggered to do your SVN update or whatever else.